# How can I read kindle book under xfce(ubuntu)? (using chromebook)(wine not working)

Tags: wine, xubuntu, xfce, chromebook

I'm using chromebook, dual booting xfce(ubuntu) and cr os. The ebook I bought on amazon is not supported on kindle cloud reader. (Under xfce)I downloaded wine and tried installing kindle for pc under wine, and after couples of times of trials, it always said installation error and could not install kindle, and it's been giving me:

```
Unhandled exception: unimplemented function msvcp90.dll.??0?$basic_ofstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAE@XZ called in 32-bit code (0x7b839cf2).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:7b839cf2 ESP:0033fcd4 EBP:0033fd38 EFLAGS:00000287(   - --  I S - -P-C)
 EAX:7b826245 EBX:7b894ff4 ECX:00000008 EDX:0033fcf4
 ESI:80000100 EDI:00dca568
Stack dump:
0x0033fcd4:  0033fd58 00000008 00000030 80000100
0x0033fce4:  00000001 00000000 7b839cf2 00000002
0x0033fcf4:  7e24b340 7e24f2ca 0000000d 00110000
0x0033fd04:  7bc47a0d 7e1dbff4 7e1417f0 00dca568
0x0033fd14:  0033fd24 7bc65d0b 00110000 00000000
0x0033fd24:  0033fd44 7e141801 7b839caa 7e1dbff4
000c: sel=0067 base=00000000 limit=00000000 16-bit r-x
Backtrace:
=>0 0x7b839cf2 in kernel32 (+0x29cf2) (0x0033fd38)
  1 0x7e24b2a8 in msvcp90 (+0x3b2a7) (0x0033fd68)
  2 0x7e216c9d in msvcp90 (+0x6c9c) (0x0033fde8)
  3 0x00938fdd in kindle (+0x538fdc) (0x0033fde8)
  4 0x0089dc71 in kindle (+0x49dc70) (0x0033fe70)
  5 0x7b859cdc call_process_entry+0xb() in kernel32 (0x0033fe88)
  6 0x7b85af4f in kernel32 (+0x4af4e) (0x0033fec8)
  7 0x7bc71db0 call_thread_func_wrapper+0xb() in ntdll (0x0033fed8)
  8 0x7bc7486d call_thread_func+0x7c() in ntdll (0x0033ffa8)
  9 0x7bc71d8e RtlRaiseException+0x21() in ntdll (0x0033ffc8)
  10 0x7bc49f4e call_dll_entry_point+0x61d() in ntdll (0x0033ffe8)
0x7b839cf2: subl    $4,%esp
Modules:
Module    Address            Debug info    Name (130 modules)
PE      340000-  37d000    Deferred     ssleay32
PE      390000-  3ca000    Deferred     webcoreviewer
PE      3d0000-  3e0000    Deferred     pthreadvc2
PE      400000- 1433000    Export       kindle
PE     1440000- 155c000    Deferred     libeay32
PE     1560000- 169f000    Deferred     qtscript4
PE     16a0000- 1795000    Deferred     libxml2
PE     17a0000- 18c7000    Deferred     javascriptcore
PE     18d0000- 1974000    Deferred     cflite
PE     1980000- 2048000    Deferred     libwebcore
PE     2050000- 208d000    Deferred     libjpeg
PE    10000000-10a34000    Deferred     qtwebkit4
PE    4a800000-4a8eb000    Deferred     icuuc46
PE    4a900000-4aa36000    Deferred     icuin46
PE    4ad00000-4bb80000    Deferred     icudt46
PE    5a4c0000-5a4d4000    Deferred     zlib1
PE    61000000-61056000    Deferred     qtxml4
PE    62000000-62093000    Deferred     qtsql4
PE    64000000-640ef000    Deferred     qtnetwork4
PE    65000000-657b8000    Deferred     qtgui4
PE    67000000-67228000    Deferred     qtcore4
PE    78050000-780b9000    Deferred     msvcp100
PE    78aa0000-78b5e000    Deferred     msvcr100
ELF    7b800000-7ba15000    Dwarf           kernel32<elf>
  \-PE    7b810000-7ba15000    \            kernel32
ELF    7bc00000-7bcc3000    Dwarf           ntdll<elf>
  \-PE    7bc10000-7bcc3000    \            ntdll
ELF    7bf00000-7bf04000    Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF    7d7f7000-7d800000    Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF    7d800000-7d818000    Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF    7d818000-7d861000    Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
ELF    7d861000-7d873000    Deferred        libp11-kit.so.0
ELF    7d873000-7d8f8000    Deferred        libgcrypt.so.11
ELF    7d8f8000-7d90a000    Deferred        libtasn1.so.3
ELF    7d90a000-7d913000    Deferred        libkrb5support.so.0
ELF    7d913000-7d9e2000    Deferred        libkrb5.so.3
ELF    7da42000-7da47000    Deferred        libgpg-error.so.0
ELF    7da47000-7da6f000    Deferred        libk5crypto.so.3
ELF    7da6f000-7da81000    Deferred        libavahi-client.so.3
ELF    7da81000-7da8f000    Deferred        libavahi-common.so.3
ELF    7da8f000-7db53000    Deferred        libgnutls.so.26
ELF    7db53000-7db91000    Deferred        libgssapi_krb5.so.2
ELF    7db91000-7dbe4000    Deferred        libcups.so.2
ELF    7dc21000-7dc55000    Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE    7dc30000-7dc55000    \            uxtheme
ELF    7dc55000-7dc5b000    Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF    7dc5b000-7dc66000    Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF    7dc6a000-7dc6e000    Deferred        libkeyutils.so.1
ELF    7dc6e000-7dc73000    Deferred        libcom_err.so.2
ELF    7dca5000-7dccf000    Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF    7dccf000-7dd03000    Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF    7dd03000-7dd13000    Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF    7dd13000-7dd17000    Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF    7dd17000-7dd20000    Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF    7dd20000-7dd2a000    Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF    7dd2a000-7dd30000    Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF    7dd30000-7dd34000    Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF    7dd34000-7dd3b000    Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF    7dd3b000-7dd5c000    Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF    7dd5c000-7dd76000    Deferred        libice.so.6
ELF    7dd76000-7deaa000    Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF    7deaa000-7debc000    Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF    7debc000-7dec5000    Deferred        libsm.so.6
ELF    7ded4000-7df67000    Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE    7dee0000-7df67000    \            winex11
ELF    7df67000-7e001000    Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF    7e001000-7e023000    Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE    7e010000-7e023000    \            iphlpapi
ELF    7e023000-7e03e000    Deferred        wsock32<elf>
  \-PE    7e030000-7e03e000    \            wsock32
ELF    7e03e000-7e071000    Deferred        wintrust<elf>
  \-PE    7e040000-7e071000    \            wintrust
ELF    7e071000-7e129000    Deferred        crypt32<elf>
  \-PE    7e080000-7e129000    \            crypt32
ELF    7e129000-7e158000    Deferred        msvcr90<elf>
  \-PE    7e130000-7e158000    \            msvcr90
ELF    7e158000-7e1e5000    Deferred        msvcrt<elf>
  \-PE    7e170000-7e1e5000    \            msvcrt
ELF    7e1e5000-7e2ca000    Dwarf           msvcp90<elf>
  \-PE    7e210000-7e2ca000    \            msvcp90
ELF    7e2ca000-7e2ec000    Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE    7e2d0000-7e2ec000    \            imm32
ELF    7e2ec000-7e3de000    Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE    7e300000-7e3de000    \            oleaut32
ELF    7e3de000-7e418000    Deferred        winspool<elf>
  \-PE    7e3f0000-7e418000    \            winspool
ELF    7e418000-7e4f7000    Deferred        comdlg32<elf>
  \-PE    7e420000-7e4f7000    \            comdlg32
ELF    7e4f7000-7e51f000    Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE    7e500000-7e51f000    \            msacm32
ELF    7e51f000-7e5cc000    Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE    7e530000-7e5cc000    \            winmm
ELF    7e5cc000-7e641000    Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE    7e5e0000-7e641000    \            rpcrt4
ELF    7e641000-7e749000    Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE    7e660000-7e749000    \            ole32
ELF    7e749000-7e841000    Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE    7e750000-7e841000    \            comctl32
ELF    7e841000-7ea52000    Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE    7e850000-7ea52000    \            shell32
ELF    7ea52000-7eabc000    Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE    7ea60000-7eabc000    \            shlwapi
ELF    7eabc000-7ead5000    Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE    7eac0000-7ead5000    \            version
ELF    7ead5000-7eb35000    Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE    7eae0000-7eb35000    \            advapi32
ELF    7eb35000-7ebf2000    Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE    7eb40000-7ebf2000    \            gdi32
ELF    7ebf2000-7ed32000    Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE    7ec00000-7ed32000    \            user32
ELF    7ed32000-7ed58000    Deferred        mpr<elf>
  \-PE    7ed40000-7ed58000    \            mpr
ELF    7ed58000-7ed6e000    Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF    7ed6e000-7eddd000    Deferred        wininet<elf>
  \-PE    7ed80000-7eddd000    \            wininet
ELF    7eddd000-7ee0f000    Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE    7ede0000-7ee0f000    \            ws2_32
ELF    7ee0f000-7ee1c000    Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF    7ee1c000-7ee28000    Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF    7ee28000-7ee42000    Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF    7ee42000-7ee4b000    Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF    7efd4000-7f000000    Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF    f74a3000-f74a7000    Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF    f74a8000-f74ad000    Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF    f74ad000-f7657000    Deferred        libc.so.6
ELF    f7658000-f7673000    Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF    f7675000-f767b000    Deferred        libuuid.so.1
ELF    f7682000-f77c4000    Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF    f77c6000-f77e8000    Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF    f77e8000-f77e9000    Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid    prio (all id:s are in hex)
0000000e services.exe
    0000001f    0
    0000001e    0
    00000015    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000012 winedevice.exe
    0000001c    0
    00000019    0
    00000014    0
    00000013    0
0000001a plugplay.exe
    00000020    0
    0000001d    0
    0000001b    0
00000037 explorer.exe
    00000038    0
00000042 (D) C:\Program Files (x86)\Amazon\Kindle\Kindle.exe
    00000043    0 <==
System information:
    Wine build: wine-1.4
    Platform: i386 (WOW64)
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 3.8.11
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: what problem or error message did you get with wine ?

Comment: If its a Samsung Chromebook with an Exynos SoC it can't run wine, because of the non x86 cpu. What file type is the ebook?

Comment: bodhi.zazen, i just put the error(sorry it's super long)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kindle PC application works fine under wine 1.75 here:

What problem /error message did you get?

[image]

Comment: I just edited my post and the error message is there(sorry it's super long)

Comment: I installed wine 1.4, not sure whether that's the problem

Comment: How do you install wine 1.75? I did: sudo apt-get install wine1.75, and it gave me: E: Unable to locate package wine1.75, E: Couldn't find any package regex 'wine1.75'

Comment: http://www.tecmint.com/install-wine-on-ubuntu-and-linux-mint/ although your cpu may not run this app, you may need to use kindle cloud

Comment: you are most welcome